# Working hyperlink breaks upon page redirection back to original page

Tags: html, redirect, hyperlink

I am playing a sound by the click on a link, I know not beautiful but it works.

Well ran into a new problem today sound did not play the first time I clicked the link... But back to the question at hand.

The HTML page playing the sound the redirects the browser back to the page I intend it to after playing the sound, but then the fun begins.

Something goes afoul with the links inside the original page's HTML code, the browser for some reason "superimposes" additional information.

Where the original HTML refers to

/webapp/play_a_sound.html

The page once it is reloaded by the redirect in HTML page 2 suddenly refers to

//webapp/webapp/play_a_sound.html

Did you notice the //webapp/webapp/ difference ?

I have tried to use  to no avail, any takes on how to avoid the link degregation ?

andytest1.html

---

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>andytest1.html</title>


<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache"> 


</head><body>


<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">


<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top;">TOPMENU<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top;">
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
<tbody>
<tr>ÅÅÅÅÅÅ

</a><td style="vertical-align: top;"> <a href="../webapp/play_a_sound.html"> Play Sound</a><br>
</a>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top;">BOTTOMMENU<br>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<br>

<br>

<br>

</body>

</html>
```

---

PLAY_A_SOUND.HTML

---

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>play_a_sound.html</title>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="3;URL=..//webapp/andytest1.html/">

<body>

<EMBED src="..//webapp/sound/anysound.wav"" autostart=true loop=false volume=100 hidden=true>

</body>
</html>
```

---

This particular problem has been noted using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and Firefox 3.6.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a trailing slash where there shouldn't be one.

Replace

```
..//webapp/andytest1.html/
```

by

```
../webapp/andytest1.html
```

I assume the trailing slash is making the browser treat the HTML page like a directory, so the browser will parse any relative URLs relative to `/webapp/andytest1.html/` instead of `/webapp/`.